# How to Silverlight Invoke Javascript function in a namespace?

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I'm having a problem since I wrapped my javascript functions inside of a namespace. 
Version 1 of my code worked fine.  Originally, to call the javascript from inside Silverlight I used to use this code:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("hideMyDiv");
```

My javascript looked like this:

```
function hideMyDiv() {
$('#MyDiv').fadeOut();
```

}

Now, I've refactored my javascript to be contained in a namespace.  So it now looks like this:

```
var activity = {
message: null,
hideMyDiv: function() {
    $('#MyDiv').fadeOut();
}   };
```

I can call this refactored function in javascript, it works like before:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
activity.hideMyDiv();   });
```

But when I try to use it from Silverlight, I get this error:  Failed to Invoke: activity.updateInfo.  This is my current Silverlight code:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("activity.hideMyDiv");
```

What am I doing wrong?  (and thanks!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the correct way..

```
ScriptObject so = HtmlPage.Window.Eval("activity") as ScriptObject;
so.Invoke("hideMyDiv");
```